# Adding schema definition in openapi3.0 yaml using external .yaml file

Tags: swagger, openapi

I've **openapi3.0 YAML** file which is written according to [openapi3.0 format](https://swagger.io/specification/) and I am using `$ swagger-cli validate simple_violation_bool.yaml` and its gave `True/False` based on whether `simple_violation_bool.yaml` is valid `OpenAPI 3.0` or not.

Below is the content of my OpenAPI3.0 yaml file i.e. `simple_violation_bool.yaml` and I am trying to add schema definition using `$ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE` but it giving error during `$ swagger-cli validate simple_violation_bool.yaml`.

Below is my `simple_violation_bool.yaml` openapi3.0 YAML file.

### simple_violation_bool.yaml

```sh
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: simple_violation_bool
  license:
    name: MIT
  description: |
    Simple violation in simple_violation_bool module
externalDocs:
  description: NISE simple_violation_bool.
servers:
  - url: https://swagger.io/specification/
paths: {}

components:
  schemas:
    NISE:
      type: object
      title: The Root Schema
      required:
        - description
        - id
        - name
        - ports
      properties:
        description:
          type: string
          title: The Descripton Schema
          schema:
            $ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
        id:
          type: integer
          title: The Id Schema
          default: 0
          format: int64
          schema:
            $ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
        name:
          type: string
          title: The Name Schema
          schema:
            $ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
        ports:
          type: array
          title: The Ports Schema
          schema:
            $ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
          items:
            type: integer
            title: The items Schema
            default: 0
            schema:
              $ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
        value:
          type: object
          title: The Value Schema
          schema:
            $ref: './violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
```

And here is the content of schema definition file `violation_schema.yaml` which I am trying to add using `$ref: './violation_schema.yaml`.

### violation_schema.yaml

```sh
NISE:
  properties:
    description:
      type: string
    id:
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
    ports:
      type: array
    value:
      type: object
```

Below is the error log after I run `$ swagger-cli validate simple_violation_bool.yaml`

### Error Log:

```sh
Running swagger-cli validate on simple_violation_bool.yaml .....
Swagger schema validation failed. 
  Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/components/schemas/NISE
    Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/components/schemas/NISE/properties/value
      Additional properties not allowed: schema at #/properties/value
      Missing required property: $ref at #/properties/value
    Missing required property: $ref at #/components/schemas/NISE

JSON_OBJECT_VALIDATION_FAILED
```

#### **Any insight on this issue?**

Lastly, I've tried with some simple openapi3.0 yaml files in the same way and it's working without any issue.

### Examples which I've tried

### main.yaml

```sh
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: ping test
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8000/'
paths:
  /some/ping:
    get:
      operationId: pingGet
      responses:
        '201':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: './other.yaml#/SomeObj'
components:
  schemas: {}
```

### other.yaml

```sh
SomeObj:
  properties:
    s1:
      type: string
    s3:
      type: string
```

This simple example works without issue. i.e `$ swagger-cli validate main.yaml` outputs: **main.yaml is valid**

Looking forward to hearing soon & thanks for spending time to look into this descriptive question.

Arslan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way in which you are trying to refer to the schema defined in the `violation_schema.yaml` from `simple_violation_bool.yaml` is not correct . You do not need to define $ref: `'./violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'` line at against each property defined in the `simple_violation_bool.yaml` file . Also , since you are defining schema altogether in a different schema file `violation_schema.yaml` , you do not need to define all those values again in the `simple_violation_bool.yaml`,i.e id,name,ports,value,etc.. Let's try to understand in a simple way , lets say you were not defining a separate file for the schema, but referring it from within the same file , i.e `simple_violation_bool.yaml`, then in that case things will look something like this as below :

[image]

So ,based on below observation , i corrected your yaml files and now its validating properly .

**simple_violation_bool.yaml**

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: simple_violation_bool
  license:
    name: MIT
  description: |
    Simple violation in simple_violation_bool module
externalDocs:
  description: NISE simple_violation_bool.
  url: "https://simple_violation_bool.net"
servers:
  - url: https://swagger.io/specification/
paths: {}

components:
  schemas:
    ROOT:
      type: object
      title: The Root Schema
      $ref: 'violation_schema.yaml#/NISE'
```

**violation_schema.yaml**

```
  NISE:
      required:
        - description
        - id
        - name
        - ports
      properties:
        description:
          type: string
          title: The Descripton Schema
        id:
          type: integer
          title: The Id Schema
          default: 0
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
          title: The Name Schema
        ports:
          type: array
          title: The Ports Schema
          items:
            type: integer
            title: The items Schema
            default: 0
        value:
          type: object
          title: The Value Schema
```

> swagger-cli validate simple_violation_bool.yaml

> simple_violation_bool.yaml is valid

I hope that it resolves the issue for you . Let me know if that helps !!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and correcting the issue. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help :)